# set value to select angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
MEDService.users("GET", "", {"action" : "getUsers"})
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.data1 = data;
```

have this code, how i can set this item(get from mongo) in select on front end?
data1 have fields: username, name, password. I need just username

```
<select ng-model="??" style="display: block" >
    <option ng-selected="??"
            ng-repeat="??"
            value="???">
      ???
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: You need to complement the question with the return of JSON.

Comment: <select data-ng-mode="yourRecquiredName" data-ng-options="item.UserName as item.username for item in data1 " ></select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `data1` looks like

```
data1 = [
      {name:'Real Name1', username:'username1', password: 'secret'},
      {name:'Real Name2', username:'username2', password: 'secret'},
      {name:'Real Name3', username:'username3', password: 'secret'}
    ]
```

try

```
<select ng-model="selectedUser" ng-options="user.name for user in data1"></select>
```

The selected user will be stored in `selectedUser`, you can easily validate that by using

```
<h2>{{selectedUser}}</h2>
```

in your html.

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/pggWiNO0TpIlCLOlFtzW

Answer (score 0):

You must create another property on your scope, like selectedValue and then use this markup :

```html
 <select ng-model="$scope.selectedValue">
     <option ng-repeat="option in $scope.data1" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, could you mark it as answered ?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have something like that:

```
$scope.data1 = [
   {username: 'olga', name: 'Olga K', password: 'querty'}, 
   ....
];
```

As the result you are going to receive `username` in this case it's `olga` value.

I see two solution you can do

**First solution for string array** you may prepare your date to view.

```
$scope.data1 = $scope.data1.map(item => item.username);
```

Then your **html** may look like that

```
<select ng-model="SELECTED_PROPERTY" ng-options="o as o for o in data1"></select>
```

---

**Second soultion**
when you have object array

```
<select ng-model="SELECTED_PROPERTY" ng-options="o.username as o.name for o in data1"></select>
```

NOTE: if you never use other object properties first solution is better one cause use few RAM memory.